# Only Allow Internal Links in Broad Scrapy Web Crawl

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, filtering, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to Crawl thousands of websites. I have a large list of domains to crawl. Everything works fine just that the crawler follows external links too, which is why it crawls way too many domains than necessary. I already tried to use "allow_domains" in the SGMLlinkextractor but this does not work when I parse a huge list of domains to it.

So my question: How can I limit a broad scrapy crawl to internal links?

Any idea much appreciated.

UPDATE: The problem is caused by a allow_domains list which is too large to handle for scrapy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by modifying the SGMLlinkextractor. I added these two lines before returning the links:

```
domain = response.url.replace("http://","").replace("https://","").split("/")[0]
links = [k for k in links if domain in k.url]
```

Answer (score 1):

[OffsiteMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware) is what you should consider using:

> `class scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware`
>
> Filters out Requests for URLs outside the domains covered by the
>   spider.
>
> This middleware filters out every request whose host names aren’t in
>   the spider’s allowed_domains attribute.

Comment: this did not solve the problem. The problem is caused by a allow_domains list which is too big for scrapy to handle